# Why am I receiving errors about assigning keys in React?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I've been working through the [ReactJS demo for ASP.NET Core](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html) and I'm struggling with an error message:

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
>   Check the render method of `CommentList`. See url for more information.
>       in Comment (created by CommentList)
>       in CommentList (created by CommentBox)
>       in div (created by CommentBox)
>       in CommentBox

The message is clear, every child of an array needs a key.  The code assigns a key however and having downloaded the react console for Chrome I can also see the array and all the data that is added.

In my code I have the following:

```
class CommentList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const commentNodes = this.props.data.map(comment => (
            <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
                {comment.author}
            </Comment>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You can see that the key is assigned to the comment component and returned to the comment list.  The `id` doesn't appear to be null so I'm confused as to why I'm still getting this error message.

Can help me with where I am going wrong with this?

Here is my complete source code so far:

**js/app.jsx**

```
class CommentBox extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: [] };
        this.handleCommentSubmit = this.handleCommentSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    loadCommentsFromServer() {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', this.props.url, true);
        xhr.onload = () => {
            const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            this.setState({ data: data });
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
    handleCommentSubmit(comment) {
        const comments = this.state.data;
        // Optimistically set an id on the new comment. It will be replaced by an
        // id generated by the server. In a production application you would likely
        // use a more robust system for ID generation.
        comment.Id = comments.length + 1;
        const newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
        this.setState({ data: newComments });

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('author', comment.author);
        data.append('text', comment.text);

        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('post', this.props.submitUrl, true);
        xhr.onload = () => this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        xhr.send(data);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        window.setInterval(() => this.loadCommentsFromServer(), this.props.pollInterval);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="commentBox card">
                <h4>Comments</h4>
                <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
                <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class CommentList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const commentNodes = this.props.data.map(comment => (
            <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
                {comment.author}
            </Comment>
        ));
        return (
            <div className="commentList">
                {commentNodes}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class CommentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //Initial state?
        this.state = { author: '', text: '' };
        //Event handlers
        this.handleAuthorChange = this.handleAuthorChange.bind(this);
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleAuthorChange(e) {
        this.setState({ author: e.target.value });
    }
    handleTextChange(e) {
        this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const author = this.state.author.trim();
        const text = this.state.text.trim();
        //If inputs are null then return nothing.
        if (!text || !author) {
            return;
        }
        //Post data to the server
        this.props.onCommentSubmit({ author: author, text: text });
        //Clear form
        this.setState({ author: '', text: '' });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="commentForm">
                <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleAuthorChange} />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class Comment extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="comment">
                <p className="commentAuthor">
                    {this.props.author}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox url="/comments" submitUrl="/comments/new" pollInterval={2000} />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I am using a model for my data as I'll be introducing this to a repository later.

**Models/CommentModel**

```
namespace ReactDemo.Models
{
    public class CommentModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controllers/HomeController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ReactDemo.Models;

namespace ReactDemo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly IList<CommentModel> _comments;
        static HomeController()
        {
            _comments = new List<CommentModel>
            {
                new CommentModel
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Author = "Daniel Lo Nigro",
                    Text = "Hello ReactJS.NET World!"
                },
                new CommentModel
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Author = "Pete Hunt",
                    Text = "This is one comment"
                },
                new CommentModel
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Author = "Jordan Walke",
                    Text = "This is *another* comment"
                },
            };
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
        [Route("comments")]
        [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public ActionResult Comments()
        {
            return Json(_comments);
        }
        [Route("comments/new")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddComment(CommentModel comment)
        {
            // Create a fake ID for this comment
            comment.Id = _comments.Count + 1;
            _comments.Add(comment);
            return Content("Success :)");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the keys are unique? Have you tried using author, or something automatically generated as the key? React uses these keys for the reconciliation process. Are you also sure the right children are getting these keys?

Comment: Can you verify you're actually getting value for id ? Also this may be case-sensitive issue...Id vs id

Comment: share your: "this.props.data" contents

Comment: @Fabian-Tjoe-A-On  I can confirm that using author does work as a key and it's assigned without a problem.

Comment: I wouldn't use Author, as this might not always be unique.

Comment: @joknawe Indeed, a different unique string is better perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the good people in this question, the issue was being caused by the uppercase `Id` being set in `handleCommentSubmit`.

**Was**

```
handleCommentSubmit(comment) {
    comment.Id = comments.length + 1;
}
```

**Change to**

```
handleCommentSubmit(comment) {
    comment.id = comments.length + 1;
}
```

The confusion between uppercase and lowercase was being caused by my declaration of values in my model, I had written those in uppercase, however, the results returned by ReactJS are, of course, lowercase.

Comment: Great! If your question has been resolved, please mark your answer as the correct answer (the tick below the up/downvote) :)

Comment: I'd love to but SO doesn't let you do that for 2 days :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Id` instead of `id` for your key value, as javascript is case sensitive. Also add `.toString()`

**'Id' is being set here:**

`comment.Id = comments.length + 1;`

**Updated jsx code:**

`<Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.Id.toString()}> {comment.author} </Comment> ));`

**From React documentation:**

"The best way to pick a key is to use a **string** that uniquely identifies a list item among its siblings. Most often you would use IDs from your data as keys:"

Comment: I tried this but I get the same result.  Using the react console for chrome I can see that the Ids are there and they are unique simply running from 1-3.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use shortid for unique keys as an alternate to id, this way even if you don't have unique id from json even then key would be unique.

```
var shortid = require('shortid');
function createNewTodo(text) {
  return {
    completed: false,
    id: shortid.generate(),
    text
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your id's are probably not unique. React mostly doesn't recommend using incremental ID's. The ID's are used in the reconciliation process, see here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

Try using author as a key, or even better, try generating unique ones (with a package like `node-uuid`, or see the method provided in @tarzen chugh his answer.